# Create columns based on word matches from seprate dataframe - works but very slow

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

**df** = list of strings:

| Strings |
| --- |
| text xxx text |
| text yyy text |
| text www text |
| text eee text |
| text xxx yyyy text |

**tag_matrix_df** = matrix of columns, labels and search words

| Columns | Search | Labels |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Col1 | xxx | label1 |
| Col1 | yyy | label2 |
| Col2 | www | label3 |
| Col2 | eee | label3 |
| Col2 | xxx yyyy | label4 |

I need to add columns to df based on tag_matrix_df when search words are found within the strings from df, for example:
**df** =

| Words | Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| text xxx text | label1 |  |
| text yyy text | label2 |  |
| text www text |  | label3 |
| text eee text |  | label3 |
| text xxx yyyy text |  | label4 |

I have the following code, which seems to be working ok but it's very slow (tag_matrix_df > 5000 rows).

```
#df = Dataframe of words
#tag_matrix_df = datafreame of columns, labels and search strings
....

 def assign_label(kw, matrix_df):

    kw = kw.lower().strip()
    
    for ii, tag in matrix_df.iterrows():
      find_tag = tag['Find'].lower().strip()
      if kw != None and find_tag in kw.split():
        return tag['Label']

 flag_cols = tag_matrix_df['Flag Name'].unique()
 for flag in flag_cols:
   filtered_matrix_df = tag_matrix_df.loc[tag_matrix_df['Flag Name'] == flag]
   df[flag] = df.apply(lambda row: assign_label(row[0], filtered_matrix_df), axis=1)
```

Please also note the issue with the first and last row for tag_matrix_df where we have "xxx" within "xxx yyyy". In this instance, it should match to xxx yyyy as this is the word.

Any suggestions on a smarter implementation of this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.merge`:

```
df = pd.merge(df, tag_matrix_df, left_on='Words', right_on='Search', how='left') 
df = df.pivot(index='Words', columns='Columns', values='Labels').fillna('')
```

```
>>> df
Columns     Col1    Col2
Words
eee               label3
www               label3
xxx       label1
xxx yyyy          label4
yyy       label2
```

Comment: thanks! I think I didn't make it clear I apologise. I'm looking to match on substring, not an exact match. so if the word contains the search then I want to match it.

Comment: OK. Please update your post to change your sample. If there are multiple matches?

Comment: ok have done so, please let me know if this is clear?